# A multiple choice question for complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with complex entries. Pick out the true
statements.

1. $A$ is always similar to an upper-triangular matrix.
2. $A$ is always similar to a diagonal matrix.
3. $A$ is similar to a block diagonal matrix, with each diagonal block of size strictly less than $n$, provided $A$ has at least $2$ distinct eigenvalues.

I have solved $1$ & $2$. $1$ is true and $2$ is false.

But I cannot find how to solve $3$. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2):

This is true and the a way to see this is to consider the [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) .